# In Google Sheets I need to find a string and return true/false, or even a count into a cell so I can perform an action

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, search, vlookup, regex

In my example i have a column with Names of signs we product in our sighshop and I need to be able to isolate similar named signs So say I need to return a a value if the cell is Bud Light and only Bud Light from the following:

Bud Light
Bud Light Platinum
Bud Light Lime
Bud Light NFL

Carried out over 100 times at random.

I am trying to dig out what signage and promotions cost.

Link to [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13MD_F7_kwEYksr-0zCaUXNoMXsxwUOAAhbco0fkNe-0/edit?usp=sharing)

Edited link hopefully it is useful now.

The above sheet is a sample of what I am trying to do.

The reasoning for this is to return how much we spend on signage from a particular printer based on Brand of Beer and the type of sign it is. There may be 1000 orders in a months time and the report generated by the system lumps everything together, thus the need to dig it all out and the randomness of it all.

Comment: Please share your spreadsheet (without private or confidential data). At present, your link requires a request for access; the sheet should be accessible without requesting permission.

Comment: Would you please provide more information about "why" you need to find the value - this may influence the method employed. You also mention "carried out 100 times at random" - please explain the reason and timing for this.

Comment: Have you thought of using a "simple" filter on the "Name" column of the relevant sheet; that allows you to select the specific name, and the results in each column only for the name that you selected in the "Name" column.

Answer (score 1):

Use `REGEXMATCH` :

```
=countif(ArrayFormula(regexmatch(A1:A10,"^Bud Light$")),true)
```

This formula counts the cells who match the regex `^Bud Light$` : Match **exactly** `Bud Light`

You can add `lower()` and `proper()`to clean the range you want to test.

Comment: Would this work in reverse if I need to find just Bud? Thanks

Comment: Replace the regex with `^Bud$` to find cells with the exact string `Bud` alone but not `Bud light` for example. The operators `^` and `$` are for start and end of the string. If you want to detect cells with `Bud + anything` just use the regex `Bud` without any operator. [Reference](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a cell (B1) for the input value to compare with.
This example will match if A1:A contains the value in B1.

```
=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH($A$1:$A,B1)),TRUE)
```